# GitLab migrating projects from older version of Gitlab Instance to newer version

Tags: gitlab

There are 2 different instances of GITLAB exists in our environment

```
Test GITLAB - version 12+
DEV  GITLAB - version 16+
```

Our organization wants to migrate all the projects from TEST to DEV instance

So far we tried the following but it seems issues, merge requests, boards and labels were not getting exported / imported using the following methods

```
Method #1:  Import by Repo URL
Method #2:  Export / Import Project
```

Upgrading version from `v12 to v16` may be an option but is a lengthy process and this would require downtime

Is there any way to get everything (branches, tags, issues, merge requests, labels etc) from one GitLab instance to another?